# Дублирование модального окна

Tags: html

На главной странице сайта есть карточки с товарами. САЙТ: https://www.gls-trade.ru
На каждой карточке есть кнопочка "подробнее", в котором отображается небольшая информация.
На одну карточку у меня получилось сделать пап ап окно - чековая лента.
Пытаюсь продублировать на карточку термоэтикетка, отображается информация о чековой ленте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где именно нужно поменять, чтобы выходило то, что мне нужно.
КОД:

````
<h3 class="editable block_148033 item item-field_title item-option_704264 item-int_862618">Чековая лента</h3>
                
                
                 <!-- <p><button class="btn button button-3d editable block_148033 item item-field_button_text item-option_1 item-int_862618 jek" >Подробнее</p> -->
                
                    <button onclick="swa()" type="button" class="btn button button-3d editable block_148033 item item-field_button_text item-option_1 item-int_862618 jek">Подробнее</button>               
    <div id="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <button class="close" title="Закрыть окно" onclick="swa2()"></button>
    <p class="zag">Чековая лента</p>
    <p>Чековая лента - расходный материал для кассовых аппаратов, факсов, банкоматов, фискальных регистраторов и паркоматов. Для изготовления рулонов термоленты на наших производственных площадках используется сырье известных немецких брендов.

Наша компания готова предложить стандартные размеры чековой ленты:

57мм – 15, 17, 27, 40м

80мм – 45, 58, 80м</p>
  </div>
</div>  
                <script>
var b = document.getElementById('overlay');
function swa(){
    b.style.visibility = 'visible';
    b.style.opacity = '1';
    b.style.transition = 'all 0.7s ease-out 0s';
}
function swa2(){
    b.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    b.style.opacity = '0';
}
</script>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    ```
````

Comment: все подряд меняла, не помогает. в конечном итоге отображается инфа о чековой ленте

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: что именно надо поменять, чтобы при нажатии на другую кнопку карточки, выходила другая информация

Comment: @MAB нужно БОЛЬШЕ КОДА)

Comment: У вас же одно окно с информацией о чековой ленте. Вы его ж и показываете.

Comment: так я и спрашиваю, что нужно именно изменить, чтобы показывало другую информацию?)))
я хочу такой же поп ап на другую карточку товара, что именно надо изменить в коде, чтобы показывало на другой карточке не чековую ленту, а другой товар.
могу сейчас код прислать, но он ничего не выводит.

Comment: <div class="col_one_third  nobottommargin">
  <div class="feature-box center media-box fbox-bg">
   
   <div class="fbox-media">
    <img class="image_fade" src="<?=get_template_directory_uri()?>/files/ct_block_item_148033_1_5_image_vv2B8h3a.jpg">
   </div>
   
   <div class="fbox-desc">
    <h3 class="editable block_148033 item item-field_title item-option_704264 item-int_1">Термоэтикетка</h3>

Comment: <button onclick="swa1()" type="button" class="btn button button-3d editable block_148033 item item-field_button_text item-option_1 item-int_1 termo">Подробнее</button>  
    <div id="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <button class="close" title="Закрыть окно" onclick="swa3()"></button>
    <p class="zag">Термоэтикетка</p>

Comment: <p>Термоэтикетка - расходный материал для кассовых аппаратов, факсов, банкоматов, фискальных регистраторов и паркоматов. Для изготовления рулонов термоленты на наших производственных площадках используется сырье известных немецких брендов.

Наша компания готова предложить стандартные размеры чековой ленты:

57мм – 15, 17, 27, 40м

80мм – 45, 58, 80м</p>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: <script>
var b = document.getElementById('overlay');
function swa1(){
 b.style.visibility = 'visible';
 b.style.opacity = '1';
 b.style.transition = 'all 0.7s ease-out 0s';
}
function swa3(){
 b.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 b.style.opacity = '0';
}
</script>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: если подскажите, как правильно код отформатировать, то пришлю в хорошем варианте)))
мне кажется тут ничего непонятно

Comment: @ПростаMiha хелп ребята

Comment: @Духсообщества хелп пожалуйста